# Custom Controls in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows

I have made a custom control in which i have a button.
Now on tap of this button i want to send some data to my parent form that is displaying the custom control and display the data.

How to send data from the customcontrol.cs to the parentForm.cs ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually controls fire events to notify the parent. That way your control does not need to know anything about its parent. Data could be exposed as a property, or (if the data is related to the event) as event arguments.

Existing examples are:

- the `MouseDown` event of a control, which has `MouseEventArgs` containing the location of the "mouse"
- the `TextChanged` event of a `TextBox`, which does not have data as arguments, but lets the parent inspect the `TextBox.Text` property

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a delegate and event and eventhandler. Define the delegate and event in the custom control class and in main code add an eventhandler that subscibes to the event defined in the custom control.

There are many examples already available in the internet.

add this to your custom control code:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string msg="";
    public MyEventArgs(string s){
       msg=s;
    }
}
// Delegate declaration. 
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);
public event MyEventHandler myHandler;
protected virtual void OnUpdate(MyEventArgs e)
{
    MyEventHandler handler = myHandler;
    if (handler != null)
    {
       // Invokes the delegates.
       handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

if you need to inform the subscriber of some event in you custom control call the OnUpdate function
    ...
    //update subscriber
    OnUpdate(new MyEventArgs("Hello"));
    //the above will call the event subscriber

in your main code:

```
...
//global?
CustomControl myCC=new CustomControl();
//add after InitializeComponents?
myCC+=new myEventHandler(myEventhandlerMethod);
...
//need to add a new myEventhandlerMethod that matches the delegate definition
public void myEventHandlerMethod(object sender, MyEventArgs e){
   //here you get when the custom control fires the event in OnUpdate...
}
```

I hope I described as easy as possible.
source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16%28v=vs.90%29.aspx